# Is it possible to get the reflection declared functions in a KMM project?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations, kotlin-multiplatform

With Kotlin, I could find all methods belongs to a class with Reflection in below code. However, is there an equivalent for a KMM project?

```
fun testMethod() {
    val cls = MyClass::class
    val funs = cls.declaredFunctions
    for (f in funs) {
        if (f.hasAnnotation<MyAnnotation>()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I try to do the same thing in `CommonMain` directory of my KMM project, but it seems KMM doesn't support features like `getDeclaredMethods`, `findAnnotation`...

And another approach is to implement it per platforms with expect/actual. Now I could do it in Android side, but still have no idea how to do it in iOS side.

Comment: Reflection has [limited support on Kotlin/JS](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-reflection.html), and even less support on Kotlin/Native. There's the highly experimental [Reflekt library](https://github.com/JetBrains-Research/reflekt), which is supposed to support multiplatform reflection, but I can't recommend it yet. What are you trying to achieve? What problem would reflection solve? There might be a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case there are several test methods mark with 1 annotation, and want to get those test methods with Reflection and to invoke those methods do some data cleaning. Basically, filter out several methods with Reflection.